# How to handle exceptions thrown from within CloudPageBlob.BeginUploadFromStream

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I'm using the Azure SDK to upload a stream to an Azure Storage Blob. I want to do it async, so I use [`CloudPageBlob.BeginUploadFromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758150.aspx). Doing this, I started to think about what would happen if an exception is thrown while reading the stream. I couldn't find any information on if the exception would bubble up, so I could catch it with a try catch, or if the method would call the async callback, or what would happen.

To try it out, I wrapped my stream in a class that inherits `Stream`, and the constructor takes my stream as an argument, and keep it as a private variable. Each inherited method then just call its equal on the private stream. In the `Read()` however, I throw an exception, to see what would happen if something goes wrong while reading the stream. I then pass an instance of my streamwrapper to `BeginUploadFromStream()`, instead of the actual stream.

It turns out, when an exception is thrown, `BeginUploadFromStream()` completes and call the async callback, and no exception bubble up to where the method was first called, so I cannot catch it with a try catch. At the same time, I cannot find any info on the `IAsyncResult` passed to the callback, that an exception was thrown.

What can I do to be able to act on the fact that `BeginUploadFromStream()` didn't complete as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll see the exception when you call `EndUploadFromStream`.

Comment: Of course, wrapping `EndUploadFromStream()` in a try catch was exactly what I needed. Many thanks!